# What object reference is initialized to the Dictionary Class type reference variable?

Tags: java, dictionary

I create a class DictionaryTest to add elements and their corresponding keys into the dictionary and showing all elements and keys of the dictionary.Here my code :

```
 import java.util.Dictionary;
 import java.util.Enumeration;

 public class DictonaryTest  
 {
     public static void main(String[] args) 
     {
         Dictionary d;
         d.put(new Integer(1),new Integer(100));
         d.put(new Integer(2),new Integer(200));
         d.put(new Integer(3),new Integer(300));
         d.put(new Integer(4),new Integer(400));
         d.put(new Integer(5),new Integer(500));

         System.out.println("Size of dictionary : " + d.size());
         Enumeration ekey = d.keys();
         Enumeration eelement = d.elements();

         System.out.println("Keys in the Dictionary...");
         while(ekey.hasMoreElements()){
             System.out.println(ekey.nextElement() + "\t");
         }

         System.out.println("Elements in the Dictionary...");
         while(eelement.hasMoreElements()){
             System.out.println(eelement.nextElement() + "\t");
         }

     }

 }
```

But here will show compile error such that:
The local variable d may not have been initialized.
What object reference is initialized to the Dictionary Class type reference variable?

Comment: But Dictionary is an abstract class it can't be initialized by constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works (see lines with `// <--` for changes to your original code

```
import java.util.Dictionary;
import java.util.Hashtable; // <-- Needed for Hashtable
import java.util.Enumeration;

 public class DictonaryTest  
 {
     public static void main(String[] args) 
     {
         Dictionary d = new Hashtable(); // <-- Initialise d with a Hashtable
         d.put(new Integer(1),new Integer(100));
         d.put(new Integer(2),new Integer(200));
         d.put(new Integer(3),new Integer(300));
         d.put(new Integer(4),new Integer(400));
         d.put(new Integer(5),new Integer(500));

         System.out.println("Size of dictionary : " + d.size());
         Enumeration ekey = d.keys();
         Enumeration eelement = d.elements();

         System.out.println("Keys in the Dictionary...");
         while(ekey.hasMoreElements()){
             System.out.println(ekey.nextElement() + "\t");
         }

         System.out.println("Elements in the Dictionary...");
         while(eelement.hasMoreElements()){
             System.out.println(eelement.nextElement() + "\t");
         }

     }

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to write a class extending Dictionary or use

```
Dictionary<Integer,Integer> d = new HashTable<Integer,Integer>();
```

But since it is obsolete: why not use Map<>?

```
Map<Integer,Integer> d = new HashMap<>();

Set<Integer> keys = d.keySet();
Collection<Integer> values = d.values();
```

You can process these just as easily as the Dictionary counterparts.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, unlike C++, declaring a variable doesn't initialize it. You have to do it manually.

```
Dictionary d = new Dictionary();
```

**EDIT:** `Dictionary` is an abstract class, so you should use an implementation of it. Actually, it is nowadays [obsolete](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Dictionary.html); you should use [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) instead. Works the same way.

```
Map d = new HashMap();
```

And you should also use generics of possible:

```
Map<Integer,Integer> d = new Map<Integer,Integer>();
```

If you use `Map`, you will have to change your other code also.

```
Iterator ikey = d.keySet().iterator();
Iterator ielement = d.values().iterator();
System.out.println("Keys in the Dictionary...");
while(ikey.hasNext()){
    System.out.println(ikey.next() + "\t");
}
System.out.println("Elements in the Dictionary...");
while(ielement.hasNext()){ 
    System.out.println(ielement.next() + "\t");
}
```

Comment: `Dictionary` is abstract and cannot be instantiated. In addition, from (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Dictionary.html) "NOTE: This class is obsolete. New implementations should implement the Map interface, rather than extending this class."